# How to convert a pdf document to html document?

Tags: javascript, php

In which I should able to write the comments on particular words and should add page numbers to the pages of html file.So that I have to bookmark the pages of html file.
Please help me out

Comment: Refer this question. It will definitely give you solution. :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782751/convert-pdf-to-html-in-php

Comment: and what have you tried to achieve this?