# Embed PDF usingHTML5 with searchable text? or need plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I want to embed a PDF on my webpage that has text I would like to be searchable. Using iframe method does not seem to work (when I click inside the window, ctrl F does not let me search for it.) What is the best way for me to embed the PDF (multiple pages) so that I can search text within the PDF? Can it be done with HTMl5? Or is there some library?

I've tried the techniques on this page:
https://pdfobject.com/static.html

I an unable to find and match the text with Ctrl+F when I open up the website in any webbrowser on any of the PDFs. The Ctrl+F appears to only work with HTML text. Please help!

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)? Looks like [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) might be a solution for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is `find()` what you're looking for? Please read: this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080217/use-browser-search-ctrlf-through-a-button-in-website)

### Edit

Mousetrap is a library that allow you to assign shortcuts, May be it's possible to search documents using Mousetrap you might want to try [Mousetrap.js project](https://craig.is/killing/mice) site, [github](https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap) and [this](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/keyboard-shortcuts-website) site has some examples and maybe it's possible to find text in documents or search documents for text. Please try and read their information..

### End edit

You can't do a search in PDF files with html only, you will need other technologies however you can embed a lot of file types with `<embed>` and display them on your pages using object, embed or frames.. if you want to search text in PDF documents, it would be better to use a php extension that is able to help you out

I hope it's helpful to you

Comment: Problem is I have used <embed> as I mentioned in my OP, though was surprised that when I use Ctrl+F, I couldnt match against any text wtihin the PDF, only text that is in the HTML.

Comment: Would it solve the issue if you're able to convert the PDF file to HTML and find somthing with `find()` ? There is an [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782751/convert-pdf-to-html-in-php/20347934#20347934) to another question with a link to [PDFtoHTML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/), I hope this is helpful to you, if not I'll try to find something better for you..