# how to get html code from pdf,docx,doc using php

Tags: php, converters, docx, doc, pdf-to-html

I want to convert any pdf,docx,doc file into html code using php. with same style as in pdf. I am not getting proper solution.

```
                            Config::set('pdftohtml.bin', 'C:/poppler-0.37/bin/pdftohtml.exe');

                            // change pdfinfo bin location
                            Config::set('pdfinfo.bin', 'C:/poppler-0.37/bin/pdfinfo.exe');
                            // initiate
                            $pdf = new Gufy\PdfToHtml\Pdf($item);

                            // convert to html and return it as [Dom Object](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser)
                            $html = $pdf->html();
```

Not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and i found a github that i used with word docs. It worked fairly good then but i havent tested it of late.  try it.

https://github.com/benbalter/Convert-Word-Documents-to-HTML

Answer (score 1):

I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782751/convert-pdf-to-html-in-php/) post could help you in a first time. With this one, you'll be able to convert any pdf into HTML code using PHP.

After this, you can use the help provided by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php) to convert ***.doc*** and ***.docx*** to PDF using PHP.

I think that you can now built a function for each document extension that you want to convert into HTML.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the  pdf to html suggestion,yes its working fine but i lost my style ,paragraph from pdf.. i mean bold,images not coming for the same, please help me out on that

Comment: Also i think not work on linux server because based on .exe file.

Comment: I think that a makeshift solution could be to write a dedicated stylesheet, that will match your pdf style. I don't tried to run it on a linux server, but as little this program is, you can just install **wine** on it and run this passthru : 
`passthru("wine pdftohtml $source_pdf $output_folder/new_file_name",$b)` 
instead of the actual one.

I'll look deeper for your style issue this afternoon.

Comment: Thank you,its helping me alot,  will try that too.. mean while i also got good solution for pdfTohtml  with css and images https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9423-PHP-Convert-PDF-to-HTML-using-Poppler.html , but  i am not getting the solution for second question that is  doc,docx to html conversation. if you can put light on it littlebit

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a web service which presents an API for converting documents. I haven't tested it very thoroughly but it does seem to produce decent results at converting Word to HTML:

https://cloudconvert.org/

Comment: Thank you, i have successfully, but its paid service...i need something  core and also i cannot use on further. i want to search words and highlight , so this solution added extra tags due to that i can not  search work