# Can not show matrix in html

Tags: php, html, matrix

I have a php code but don't know how to show it in HTML table. I created matrix tables to add and multiply but don't know how to put results in HTML table. I tried to put the code between script tags but it didn't work. My matrix func basically generates 4 by 4 matrices with random integers and generates two matrices called A and B. then I created two other functions to add and multiply these matrices but I didn't print them out in HTML table.
My code:

```
// creating function addMatrix which takes two numbers and returns a new matrix
function addMatrix($A, $B)
{
    // declaring $ADD as a empty array
    $ADD = array();
    // iterate from i is equal to 0, i is less than 4 and increment i by 1
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        // iterate from j is equal to 0, j is less than 4 and increment j by 1
        for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
            // adding $A[$i][$j] to $B[$i][$j] and store the result in $ADD[$i][$j]
            $ADD[$i][$j] = $A[$i][$j] + $B[$i][$j];
        }
    }
    // return $ADD
    return $ADD;
}

// creating function mulMatrix which takes two numbers and returns a new matrix
function mulMatrix($A, $B)
{
    // declaring $MUL as a empty array
    $MUL = array();
    // iterate from i is equal to 0, i is less than 4 and increment i by 1
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        // iterate from j is equal to 0, j is less than 4 and increment j by 1
        for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
            // assign 0 in $MUL[$i][]
            $MUL[$i][] = 0;
            // iterate from k is equal to 0, k is less than 4 and increment k by 1
            for ($k = 0; $k < 4; $k++) {
                // multiply $ADD[$i][$k] with $B[$k][$j] then add it in $MUL[$i][$j] and store it
                // in $MUL[$i][$j]
                $MUL[$i][$j] += $A[$i][$k] * $B[$k][$j];
            }
        }
    }
    // return $MUL
    return $MUL;
}


// generate matrix by calling generateMatrix and store it in $A
$A = generateMatrix();
// generate matrix by calling generateMatrix and store it in $B
$B = generateMatrix();
// add matrix by calling addMatrix and store it in $ADD
$ADD = addMatrix($A, $B);
// mul matrix by calling mulMatrix and store it in $MUL
$MUL = mulMatrix($A, $B);

// create element table and th
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10'><th colspan=4>Matrix 'A'</th>";
// iterate from i is equal to 0, i is less than 4 and increment i by 1
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    // create element tr
    echo "<tr>";
    // iterate from j is equal to 0, j is less than 4 and increment j by 1
    for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
        // display value of $A[$i][$j] with element td
        echo "<td>" . $A[$i][$j] . "</td>";
    }
    // create element end tr table
    echo "</tr>";
}
// create element end tag table
echo "</table>";
// create element br
echo "<br>";

// create element table and th
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10'><th colspan=4>Matrix 'B'</th>";
// iterate from j is equal to 0, j is less than 4 and increment j by 1
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    // create element tr
    echo "<tr>";
    // iterate from j is equal to 0, j is less than 4 and increment j by 1
    for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
        // display value of $A[$i][$j] with element td
        echo "<td>" . $B[$i][$j] . "</td>";
    }
    // create element end tr table
    echo "</tr>";
}
// create element end tr table
echo "</table>";


// create element br
echo "<br>";
// create element table and th
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10'><th colspan=4>Matrix 'A' + 'B'</th>";
// iterate from i is equal to 0, i is less than 4 and increment i by 1
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    // create element tr
    echo "<tr>";
    // iterate from j is equal to 0, j is less than 4 and increment j by 1
    for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
        // display value of $ADD[$i][$j] with element td
        echo "<td>" . $ADD[$i][$j] . "</td>";
    }
    // create element end tr table
    echo "</tr>";
}
// create element end tr table
echo "</table>";

// create element br
echo "<br>";
// create element table and th
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10'><th colspan=4>Matrix 'A' * 'B'</th>";
// iterate from i is equal to 0, i is less than 4 and increment i by 1
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    // create element tr
    echo "<tr>";
    // iterate from j is equal to 0, j is less than 4 and increment j by 1
    for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
        // display value of $MUL[$i][$j] with element td        
        echo "<td>" . $MUL[$i][$j] . "</td>";
    }
    // create element end tr table
    echo "</tr>";
}
// create element end tr table
echo "</table>";here
```

Comment: There is already a question answered about this subject:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782751/convert-pdf-to-html-in-php

Comment: it is not the thing that I asked. There is nothing to do with pdf???

Comment: Can you clarify what happens when you run the code you've shown? Does the HTML table not display at all, display the wrong information, display some values but not others...?

Comment: it doesnt return anything when i copy paste code to html

Comment: Fist of all, enable error reporting, that will help you solve this issue better then us. Function `generateMatrix` is not present in your question, could be wrong, who knows. The `<th colspan=4>Matrix 'A'</th>` etc. should be wraped inside `<tr></tr>`, but i dubt thats the cause, browsers autocorrect these. Otherwise everything looks fine except the `here` typo at the end of file.

Comment: You haven't defined generateMatrix(). brain@earth:/tmp$ php x.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function generateMatrix() in /tmp/x.php:45

As @Kazz said, set display_errors in php.ini to on. restart your webserver.

Otherwise you just see blank page if there is error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any HTML tag. Maybe it's a partial codebase because the definition of generateMatrix is also missing. You can try this syntax to print the matrix,

```
    <!-- create element table and th -->
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10'>
    <th colspan=4>Matrix 'A'</th>
    <?php
        // iterate from i is equal to 0, i is less than 4 and increment i by 1
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            // create element tr
            echo "<tr>";
            // iterate from j is equal to 0, j is less than 4 and increment j by 1
            for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
                // display value of $A[$i][$j] with element td
                echo "<td>" . $A[$i][$j] . "</td>";
            }
            // create element end tr table
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
<!--  create element end tag table -->
</table>
<!-- create element br -->
<br>

<!-- create element table and th -->
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10'>
    <th colspan=4>Matrix 'B'</th>
    <?php 
        // iterate from j is equal to 0, j is less than 4 and increment j by 1
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            // create element tr
            echo "<tr>";
            // iterate from j is equal to 0, j is less than 4 and increment j by 1
            for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
                // display value of $A[$i][$j] with element td
                echo "<td>" . $B[$i][$j] . "</td>";
            }
            // create element end tr table
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
<!-- create element end tr table -->
</table>
<!-- create element br -->
<br>

<!-- create element table and th -->
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10'>
    <th colspan=4>Matrix 'A' + 'B'</th>
    <?php
        // iterate from i is equal to 0, i is less than 4 and increment i by 1
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            // create element tr
            echo "<tr>";
            // iterate from j is equal to 0, j is less than 4 and increment j by 1
            for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
                // display value of $ADD[$i][$j] with element td
                echo "<td>" . $ADD[$i][$j] . "</td>";
            }
            // create element end tr table
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
<!-- create element end tr table -->
</table>

<!-- create element br -->
<br>
<!-- create element table and th -->
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10'>
    <th colspan=4>Matrix 'A' * 'B'</th>
    <?php
        // iterate from i is equal to 0, i is less than 4 and increment i by 1
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            // create element tr
            echo "<tr>";
            // iterate from j is equal to 0, j is less than 4 and increment j by 1
            for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
                // display value of $MUL[$i][$j] with element td        
                echo "<td>" . $MUL[$i][$j] . "</td>";
            }
            // create element end tr table
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>

<!-- create element end tr table -->
</table>
```

[image: Output]